# options.php problem - data not saved

Tags: functions, options

I've created a custom menu page with some fields. I want to store these settings to use elsewhere.

The form with the fields should save and POST data using `action="options.php"` but every time I hit save on the form it sends me back to the settings page, and does not save the data.

I'm registering the settings in my functions.php

```
function register_settings() {  
        register_setting('settings-group','phonenumber');
        register_setting('settings-group','primaryemail');
        register_setting('settings-group','secondemail');
    }
```

This is the form action

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">
```

Here is the full code which is in functions.php http://pastebin.com/zVhSLZ9d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
<?php settings_fields( 'settings-group' ); ?>
<?php do_settings_sections( 'settings-group' ); ?>
```

immediately after the `<form>` tag

Your code is registering the settings group, setting up the DB to store the information, but it is/was missing the callback to allow WordPress to actually act on that information or store it.

The code I provided tells WordPress what to access, and what to do with the form.

Comment: Please explain *why*

Comment: @PieterGoosen I fully intended to, but the mobile app cut me off for some reason - Explanation now added - thanks for the reminder!